# In VS Code, is there a way to access the individual variables in the c_cpp_properties.json file from tasks.json

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I want to be able to define things like include paths, files to compile, compiler flags, library paths and libraries...etc in one file and then reference those in both my active configuration (c_cpp_properties.json) and tasks (tasks.json).  If I understand correctly, the c_cpp_properties.json file is there to help the C++ extension do intellisense accurately, but has no role in the actual compilation.  I figured I could use that file to store this information since intellisense needs it anyway.  Currently to compile and link, I need to duplicate many of the items in the c_cpp_properties.json file in my tasks.json file.  I was hoping there was a way to define these once and then refer to them as a variable.  Note I have no current interest in CMake.  I want to work directly with the compiler.

What I tried was to add some environment variables to my c_cpp_properties.json file:

```json
"env": {
        "myIncludePaths": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Functions/**"
        ],
        "filesToCompile": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
            "${workspaceFolder}/Functions/*.cpp"
        ]
    }
```

Then I tried to access those below in each configuration:

```json
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32 Debug",
            "includePath": [
                "${myIncludePaths}"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22621.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-clang-x64",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-std=${cppStandard}",
                "-g",
                "${filesToCompile}"
            ],
            "customConfigurationVariables": {
                "OutDir": "${workspaceFolder}/Debug"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Win32 Release",
            "includePath": [
                "${myIncludePaths}"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22621.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-clang-x64",
            "cppStandard": "c++20",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-std=${cppStandard}",
                "${filesToCompile}"
            ],
            "customConfigurationVariables": {
                "OutDir": "${workspaceFolder}/Release"
            }
        }
    ]
```

There's some information in the c_cpp_properties.json [reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference#_supported-variables) that says:

> You can allow `tasks.json` or `launch.json` to query the current active configuration from `c_cpp_properties.json`. To do this, use the variable `${command:cpptools.activeConfigName}` as an argument in a `tasks.json` or `launch.json` script.

However there is no examples I can find on how to actually do this.

I was able to successfully reference `customConfigurationVariables` (located in `c_cpp_properties.json`):

```json
"customConfigurationVariables": {
    "OutDir": "${workspaceFolder}/Release"
}
```

in my `task.json` like this:

```json
"inputs": [
    {
        "id": "OutDir",
        "type": "command",
        "command": "cpptools.activeConfigCustomVariable",
        "args": "OutDir"
    }
],
"tasks": [
    {
    "type": "cppbuild",
    "label": "Build current config",
    "command": "C:/Program Files/LLVM/bin/clang++.exe",
    "args": [
        "${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp",
        "${workspaceFolder}\\Functions\\*.cpp",
        "-I",
        "${workspaceFolder}\\Functions\\",
        "-o",
        "${input:OutDir}\\app.exe",
    ],
...
...
...
```

However I'm unable to find a way to access other variables like `includePath`, `compilerArgs` ... etc

It sounds like a way was added to do what I want to do, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: If you can, I don't know of it. Very annoying that you have to specify stuff like this in two places. It revolts me and breaks one of the few hard rules of programming: Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: My solution to this problem is not to use `c_cpp_properties.json` but then I really dislike intellisense, so it's easy for me.

Comment: Just don't use tasks.json or c_cpp_properties.json. use a proper build system, ideally one with a vscode plugin that automatically configures intellisense or at least produces compile_commands.json which can be used instead

Comment: @AlanBirtles `tasks.json` is fine (and can be used to run your build system of choice), it's just `c_cpp_properties.json` that's problematic.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, but if you don't use it and use a plugin instead (I believe there's one for most build systems now) you don't need to fiddle with either json file